# how to force user to enable macros in the sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a template with macros to validate the data on clicking the button. The template having only one sheet and no sheets added in that file (It should have one sheet only). Now, I have to do is, when the file is open without macros enabled, i need to display a image, please enable macros other wise no need to display.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

Comment: If you can force user to enable macro, then bad guys can force user to run malicious macros.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, How to over come this issue. Please help....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how to force user to enable macros in the sheet?

The answer to your question is "**You Can't**"

However here is an alternative by Ken Puls which will suit your purpose just fine.

**Topic**: Force users to enable macros in a workbook

**Link**: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=379

QUOTE FROM THAT LINK

> Since there is no way to use a macro to turn on macros, a technique to ensure the user has enabled macros is desirable. This particular method hides all sheets except a "welcome" sheet which tells the user to enable macros, and is enforced every time the workbook is saved. If the user opens the workbook with macros enabled, the sheets will all be unhidden by the macro. The hiding of sheets is also done using Excel VeryHidden property, which means that the sheets cannot be unhidden using Excel's menus. Keep in mind, however, that this only affects this workbook, so a user could use a macro from another workbook to unhide all of your sheets. Chances are, however, if your user is that skilled, they can always get into your file anyway. NOTE: To prevent some event looping issues, this code requires overruling Excel's built in Save events, and also requires replicating Excel's "Workbook has changed, do you want to save" prompts and actions. This code takes care of all of it. It does, however, create a very minor issue when closing the file. If the user trys to quit the application, it will close the workbook, but not Excel. Quitting again will close Excel completely.

**FOLLOWUP**

Before you close the Workbook do the following

1. Insert a new Row
2. Increase the height of the row
3. Hide the rest of the rows
4. Resize and Move picture at a relevant location

And when you open do the reverse of above

1. Unhide the rest of the rows
2. Delete the 1st Row
3. Decrease the size and Move the picture to a far left location in the sheet

**Important**.

When you place the picture on the sheet, right click on the picture and click on 'Format Picture'. In the `Format Picture Dialog`, select `Don't move or size with cells` and uncheck the option which says `Print Object`

[image]

**CODE WHEN CLOSING THE WORKBOOK - Apply the same concept as shown in the above link**

```
Dim shp As Shape

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Rows(1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    .Rows(1).RowHeight = 300

    .Rows("2:" & .Rows.Count).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Set shp = .Shapes("Picture 1")
    With shp
        .Top = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Top
        .Left = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Left
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Height = 100
        .Width = 100
    End With
End With
```

**CODE WHEN OPENING THE WORKBOOK - Apply the same concept as shown in the above link**

```
Dim shp As Shape

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Rows("1:" & .Rows.Count).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    .Rows(1).Delete

    Set shp = .Shapes("Picture 1")
    With shp
        .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .Height = 0
        .Width = 0
        .Top = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Top
        .Left = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("IV1").Left
    End With
End With
```

NOTE: In the above code, replace `"Sheet1"` with the relevant sheet name and replace `"Picture 1"` with the relevant picture name. I am showing the image in Cell `A1`. You can amend that to display the picture where ever you want by adjusting `.Top` and `.Left` of the Shape.

**SNAPSHOT IF MACRO IS DISABLED**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Siddharth for your support in solving issues. But i have only one sheet in the file and no sheets to be added to that file. In given example we need to add one more sheet. Please help to do the same in one worksheet. Thanks

Comment: Increase the height of Row 1 (hide rest of the rows) and show an image and if the macros are enabled then reduce the height back to normal and move the image to the far right of the worksheet. Let me know if you want an example?

Comment: please give the example. Thanks

Comment: Sure. Do you want to display an Image or a Message would also suffice?

Comment: I have designed a image displaying "Please enable macros on your template". I need to display that image if the Macros are disabled otherwise it should be disappear.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12777/discussion-between-user1049518-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: Code Updated in the post above.

Comment: Thank you Siddharth, Its working great. I have one doubt, there is any relation between the picture and the cell ?

Comment: No, I am just using the cell's `.Top` and `.Left` to place my picture... That's it :)